# Read Keystroke across multiple threads and execute function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, opencv, camera

I have a script which views 4 usb cameras in individual tabs, and takes a picture when the space bar is pressed. However, when pressing the space bar in a specific preview window, it takes a picture of that, and only that preview. Similarly, pressing esc quits the window I am focused on, but I have to do this for every camera preview window in order to quit the script. Is there a way to have quit events and capture events all happen on the same keystroke? Or is this not possible with multithreading?

```
import cv2
import threading

class camThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, previewName, camID):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.previewName = previewName
        self.camID = camID

    def run(self):
        print("Starting " + self.previewName)
        camPreview(self.previewName, self.camID)

def camPreview(previewName, camID):
    cv2.namedWindow(previewName)
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camID)
    if cam.isOpened():
        rval, frame = cam.read()
    else:
        rval = False

    while rval:
        cv2.imshow(previewName, frame)
        rval, frame = cam.read()
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 27:  # exit on ESC
            break
        key = cv2.waitKey(20)
        if key == 32:
            img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(camID)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
            print("{} written!".format(img_name))
    cv2.destroyWindow(previewName)

# Create threads as follows

thread1 = camThread("Camera 1", 0)
thread2 = camThread("Camera 2", 1)
thread3 = camThread("Camera 3", 2)
thread4 = camThread("Camera 4", 3)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread3.start()
thread4.start()
print()
print("Active threads", threading.activeCount())
```

Comment: threads should use shared variable or queues to share information about key.

Comment: Why is this tagged Python 2? Can you confirm which version you’re using?